Is there any way to approximate a function based on a series of logarithm
Is there a way to expand a function in terms of logarithmic series? Like when we expand a function in terms of Taylor or Fourier series?
I tried to answer this question this way: Let's assume it can be done. In this case, it may be possible to write:
$
f(x) = \sum a_i \ln(b_i x) = \sum a_i \ln(bi) + \sum a_i \ln(x) = \sum c_i + \sum a_i \ln(x)
$
But this does not seem to lead me to the answer. Even if this could be done by putting some special conditions on the function, that would be convincing to me.

it's just a change of variables; $f(\ln y)$ can be expanded in a Taylor series in powers of $\ln y$

The displayed equation boils down to $f(x)=A+B\log x$ where $A=\sum a_i\log(b_i)$ and $B=\sum a_i$ are constants, so it won't get you very far with expanding any other kind of function.

@CarloBeenakker Please explain more about it. I can not understand that how a simple change of variable is enough.

@GerryMyerson  Yes. It is not a good idea. But, I have no other idea.

for example $1/(1-\ln y)=1+\ln y + \ln^2 y + \ln^3 y + \cdots$, which converges for $y$ near 1.

Ok. But, in your example both sides are written w.r.t. $\ln y$. Whereas I need the LHS   w.r.t. $y$ and the RHS  w.r.t. $\ln y$.
